# NSData bytes readonly?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

According to the [GNUstep documentation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSData.html#method$NSData-bytes), `[NSData bytes]` returns `const void*`.

Does that mean that I'm not supposed to modify the data referenced by that pointer?

Currently I'm modifying the data, and it works for me. I can write to a file and the modified data go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSData is unmutable by definition. Use NSMutableData instead.`

```
NSMutableData *mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
void *pointerToMutableBytes = [mutableData mutableBytes];
```

Comment: The term is *immutable*.